# Nor able to parse the SAR output

Tags: sar

We are using SuSE 10 OS and lately I wish to know the total network bandwidth used for a period of time lets say for 1 week.

We have sar enabled and the sar data for a week is there.

Now I know how to use sar command to provide network information but it gives me the data per second. like

sar -n DEV -f /var/log/sa/sar1

provides the data for the whole day like this,

IFACE rxpck/s txpck/s rxbyt/s txbyt/s rxcmp/s txcmp/s rxmcst/s 08:50:01 PM lo 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 08:50:01 PM eth0 0.79 0.22 90.10 18.63 0.00 0.00 0.01 08:50:01 PM eth1 2.41 1.54 296.88 222.52 0.00 0.00 0.00 08:50:01 PM sit0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Average: lo 106.77 106.77 22108.66 22108.66 0.00 0.00 0.00 Average: eth0 326.83 488.07 31915.20 18195.22 0.00 0.00 0.01 Average: eth1 121.15 126.26 25931.07 38040.48 0.00 0.00 0.00 Average: sit0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

So how do I know the total network bandwidth (not the average) used?

Any pointers please? Thanx.

•Admin

Comment: Maybe the wrong file (or the file doesn't contain the whole day)? 
The file 'sar1' is the ascii version of your sysstat file, try 'sar -n DEV -f /var/log/sa/sa1' instead.

Comment: No..but we get the proper output using the file. It just that I am getting the output for "rxpck/s txpck/s rxbyt/s" which are packets per seconds .... and is by default I think. So how do we get/calculate the total bandwidth from this.